# Why does the Postfix proxymap process keeps failing?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, domain

I recently took the dark path to managing my own VPS with shell access (CentOS 5). I installed the LAMP stack, FTP etc. then setting up mail server I used postfix, dovecot and squirrel mail as client. After going through different tutorials online, I've succeeded in failing. This is a sample of the mail log:

```
Jul 20 01:18:16 www postfix/smtpd[1287]: warning: private/proxymap socket: service dict_proxy_open: Connection reset by peer
Jul 20 01:18:16 www postfix/master[1125]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/proxymap pid 7431 exit status 1
Jul 20 01:18:16 www postfix/master[1125]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/proxymap: bad command startup -- throttling
Jul 20 01:19:16 www postfix/proxymap[7449]: fatal: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Jul 20 01:19:17 www postfix/cleanup[1141]: warning: premature end-of-input on private/proxymap socket while reading input attribute name
Jul 20 01:19:17 www postfix/cleanup[1141]: warning: private/proxymap socket: service dict_proxy_open: Success
Jul 20 01:19:17 www postfix/smtpd[1287]: warning: premature end-of-input on private/proxymap socket while reading input attribute name
Jul 20 01:19:17 www postfix/smtpd[1287]: warning: private/proxymap socket: service dict_proxy_open: Connection reset by peer
Jul 20 01:19:17 www postfix/master[1125]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/proxymap pid 7449 exit status 1
Jul 20 01:19:17 www postfix/master[1125]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/proxymap: bad command startup -- throttling
```

I cant get mail to be sent out or received. please help, I'm willing to paste any info as required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this error message `fatal: unsupported dictionary type: mysql`, your postfix compiled without MySQL support. See [Postfix MySQL Howto](http://www.postfix.org/MYSQL_README.html).

Comment: ok thx, ive fixed that, now i can send mail but cannot see or receive mail in the inbox. im starting to suspect its a squirrelmail issue

Comment: I recommend opening another question with appropriate details and logs included.

Answer (score 1):

just to add.. easy way to tell if mysql is compiled in

```
# ldd /usr/sbin/postfix  | grep sql
libmysqlclient.so.15 => /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15 (0x00002b7db008d000)
```

Comment: [root@veepiz ~]# ldd /usr/sbin/postfix  | grep sql
        libmysqlclient.so.15 => /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15 (0x00007f7751f23000)

Comment: It is even **easier** to issue `postconf -m` and look if it returns `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Additional hint for debian systems: install the package postfix-mysql:

```
apt-get install postfix-mysql
```